# Is there a counterpart of five:registerPackage initialize to uninstall?

Tags: testing, plone, uninstallation, zope, monkeypatching

I hit [this bug](https://github.com/plone/collective.indexing/issues/9), in short `collective.indexing` monkey patches various packages, and although I manually uninstall it on the layer tear down, the patches are still around when another layer is brought up and tests are run on that new layer.

On its configure.zcml it has:

```
<five:registerPackage package="." initialize=".initialize" />
```

**So, is there a way to hook an uninstall method just like there is an install one?**

In fact I already have the code to [remove the monkey patches](https://github.com/plone/collective.indexing/pull/10).